# Не найден ресурс: Resource "style/application.css" not found

Tags: java, css, javafx

Мне нужно присоединить к проекту css файл, но у меня вылетает ошибка: Resource "style/application.css" not found

Вот сам код:

````
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml")));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(0,"style/application.css");
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:src/main/java/com/example/javafx/assets/icon.png"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("First JavaFX project");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

"./style/application.css"

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Все равно ошибка. Путь указан верно, но ошибка не пропадает